# Add tailwind classes manually

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I use a tailwind class, which is only add with JS afterwards.
However, when I generate the css from tailwind this CSS class is of course not included. Therefore the question how I can add this class.

Answer (score 3):

Tailwind allows to safelist classes:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Add the following to your tailwind.config.js:

```
 safelist: [
    'class-name-you-need-to-add'
  ]
```

The documentation also explains how to use regular expressions to safelist multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure Tailwind so that it will also scan your JS files that are adding these additional classes. This can be done by modifying `tailwind.config.js` file and add additional entries/glob patterns to the `content` array, [as per documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration).

Under the hood Tailwind CSS uses regex to simply search for possible classname uses in JS files. This also means that you need to be mindful of how you're adding classes in JS. You cannot use dynamically composited class names, e.g. `const className = 'px-' + SOME_NUMBER`, because Tailwind CSS cannot guess the class name.

Answer (score -1):

You can customize Tailwind CSS by changing lines under `themes` section in your `tailwind.config.js` file. About more details: [Tailwind Custom Styles](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles)

Comment: I don't think that's what OP is looking for. The issue OP has is that Tailwind is not detecting Tailwind-specific class names being used in JS files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).